# A/B testing impact of two different product pricing strategies on revenue

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

**Scenario**

I am running a marketplace with 100,000 products available for purchase on my website. In most months between 1000-10000 different products are sold. This means that in any given month the majority of products are not sold.

I want to change my pricing algorithm from version A to version B to increase total revenue.

**Proposed test**

Price 50,000 randomly selected products with pricing algorithm A (group A) and the other 50,000 products with pricing algorithm B (group B).

Collect sales data for all products over a period of time.

After running the test for a while use a t-test to compare the differences in mean revenue (price * units sold) produced per product in each group.

**Open questions**

- Is comparing the mean revenue per product the right metric?
- The majority of products will have a revenue of 0EUR at the end of the experiment. Does this cause any issues?
- How would you decide when to stop the experiment? After a certain number of purchases have been made? After a certain number of products have generated a non-negative revenue?

Comment: Why would you randomize on product and not on user (i.e. randomize users to new vs old algorithm)

Comment: Technical constraints.

Comment: The main issue with product-level randomization is that you will have treatment spillovers for complements or substitutes. An extreme example of the latter: imagine you raised the price of the left shoes by 50% and lowered the cost of the right shoes by 50%. Not much would change (unless you have a lot of pirate customers), but that doesn't imply changing your prices does not alter the quantity demanded.

Comment: In that case, it's probably better to randomize clusters of products linked by substitute and complement relationships so that clusters are more independent. However, that can lower power and cause you to run the test longer. Is that a concern here?

Comment: Thanks @dimitriy. Test length is not a concern. But I am still unsure on the questions above. How would you even determine when the experiment is complete? Based on numbers of products purchased? Based on number of buyer purchases?

Comment: While I am certain your boss will not be happy with an 18-month experiment, the length is determined by a power calculation. You decide what a meaningful diff means to you (say 1% revenue) and then use the mean and standard deviation of revenue per product per day (including zeros) and the number of products to set length. Typically, the length will be in days.